# casting gl_VertexID from int to float very slow

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am rendering an octree that contains points to a FBO.

I want a way to identify the points I am rendering.

To do so, I set an ID to each of the octree nodes (16bit integer). And I use gl_VertexID to identify a point in a node (no more than 65k points per nodes)

I output this to a RGBA texture with the octree node identifier written to the `rg` color components and the vertex ID writtent to the `ba` color components.

```
vec4 getIdColor() {
    float r = mod(nodeID, 256.0) / 255.0;
    float g = (nodeID / 256.0) / 255.0;
    float b = mod(gl_VertexID, 256.0) / 255.0;
    float a = (gl_VertexID/ 256.0) / 255.0;

    return vec4(r, g, b, a);
}
```

The problem is that the gl_VertexID cast from int to float is really slow (I go from 60FPS to 2-3 FPS when rendering 2 million points).

EDIT : I also have the exact same problem when just using `gl_VertexID`. If I remove the mods and juste write

```
return vec4(gl_VertexID);
```

I have the same hit on the framerate. So the problems comes from gl_VertexID, not the mod

Is there a workaround (also, what causes this ?)

Comment: You're returning a `vec4` from a `void` function? Also, *why* are you casting it to a `float`, just to do `mod` (which makes more sense with integers).

Comment: @3Dave It is a `vec4` function. Made a mistake when I wrote the example above.
Whether I cast it "by hand" or through `mod(gl_VertexID, 256.0)`, I have the same hit on my framerate, so there is something wrong somewhere. I edited my question

Comment: @Ebatsin: What makes you think this is a casting problem? Also, what hardware do you have?

Comment: @NicolBolas I thought at first it was a casting problem but it was a random guess since the problem appeared after I added the cast. I now think it comes from gl_VertexID. I have a GTX 1070 running on Windows 10 (driver version : 391.35)

Comment: Please show the full shader.

Comment: @derhass This is the full shader. There is a big uniform struct at the begining that contains (among other things) the `nodeID` and that's all, my main assign the result of this function to the output color. The problem appeared with the addition of a reference to `gl_VertexID`

Comment: and which _position_ does it assign? Or are you using transform feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In the shader, if was using a `if/else` cascade (I know it's not good practice but it was a test shader).

Seems that I went over some cache size. Generating the shaders code on the fly with only the sections which conditions evaluates to true fixed the issue. It was both the number of conditions & the access to `gl_VertexID` that slowed the rendering down.